# Search through a deep JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to find a JSON object by looking for a special key from the inside.
For example in the following case:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "usa",
    "position": 8,
    "code": 1,
    "other": false,
    "new": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "services": {
      "service_vkcom": {
        "count": 6039,
        "popular": false,
        "code": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "service": "Вконтакте",
        "slug": "vkcom"
      },
      "service_3223": {
        "count": 4053,
        "popular": false,
        "code": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "service": "Facebook",
        "slug": 3223
      }
}
```

Looking up the word "usa," I'd like the whole "1" thing to come back to me.

Comment: How deep could the word be buried? Only the first level? What have you tried? Any code to show?

Comment: And do you know which fields you want to search...or any field? Your criteria is a bit vague

Comment: Since my JSON is not in a array, I can't do any filter, some etc... Indeed my name can't be lower than in my example above.

Comment: @charlietfl I only want to search by name and return the entire object associated with the name (in my example, it's 1)

Comment: Well actually you can use array methods on `Object.entries(yourObject)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries or similarly on Object.values

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this will not work for deep objects

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceCherone but as mentionned Eugen Sunic, this will not work for deep objects

Comment: Again that's where your given criteria is a bit vague since you just commented that you only need to check `name` but none of the deeper objects have that property

Comment: I can't retreive informations inside services in my example and with the code of @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search `recursively` for the value and return the object it's in:

```js
let obj = {
  "1": {
    "name": "usa",
    "position": 8,
    "code": 1,
    "other": false,
    "new": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "services": {
      "service_vkcom": {
        "count": 6039,
        "popular": false,
        "code": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "service": "Вконтакте",
        "slug": "vkcom"
      },
      "service_3223": {
        "count": 4053,
        "popular": false,
        "code": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "service": "Facebook",
        "slug": 3223
      }
    }
  }
};

function getParent(obj, val) {
    let res = []; 
    for(let p in obj)
        if (typeof(obj[p]) == 'object')
            res = res.concat(getParent(obj[p], val));
        else if (obj[p] == val) 
            res.push(obj);
    return res;
}

console.log(getParent(obj, "usa"));
console.log(getParent(obj, 6039));
console.log(getParent(obj, "Facebook"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that uses [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = {"1":{"name":"usa","position":8,"code":1,"other":false,"new":false,"enabled":true,"services":{"service_vkcom":{"count":6039,"popular":false,"code":1,"id":1,"service":"Вконтакте","slug":"vkcom"},"service_3223":{"count":4053,"popular":false,"code":1,"id":2,"service":"Facebook","slug":3223}}}};

const find = (obj, name) => objectScan(['**.name'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === name
})(obj);

console.log(find(data, 'usa'));
// => { name: 'usa', position: 8, code: 1, other: false, new: false, enabled: true, services: { service_vkcom: { count: 6039, popular: false, code: 1, id: 1, service: 'Вконтакте', slug: 'vkcom' }, service_3223: { count: 4053, popular: false, code: 1, id: 2, service: 'Facebook', slug: 3223 } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)